# Hiding a file from other programs

Tags: c++, file, hide

I need to make a file not appear to another program. For instance, when another program gets the list of files in a folder, I want one particular one not to show up. I am injecting a DLL from which my code will run into the process from which I want to hide the DLL file on the filesystem. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and Windows 7.

Comment: This sounds pretty dodgy!  I would hazard a guess and say that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, as you've mentioned you need to intercept the file/folder enumeration APIs and filter out the specific file/folder from the enumeration result in order to "hide" that file/folder. This can be done either at user mode or kernel mode.
**User mode:** User mode hooking involves DLL injection. There are many places where you can hook:

- IAT hooking of executables: Find out the entry FindXxx in import address table of the target process and overwrite it with the address of trampoline function present in injected DLL.
- EAT hooking of DLLs loaded by executables: Find out the entry of FindXxx APIs in export address table of loaded DLL (kernel32.dll in this case) and overwrite it with the address of trampoline function present in injected DLL.
- Inline hooking: Overwriting first few instructions of an API code in a loaded DLL with a JMP to your trampoline function.

Generally, user mode tend to become "ugly" (difficult to manage) as you need inject your DLL into all of the running processes if you want a system-wide hook (or at least into Explorer.exe or your target application). Many applications, like security software, have protection mechanisms to detect and deny DLL injection.
A cleaner way to implement user mode hooking is to hook APIs in NTDLL.dll (using either EAT or inline hook). All other APIs (like FindFirstFile/FindNextFile) end up calling an equivalent NtXxx APIs (like NtQueryDirectoryFile) provided by NTDLL.dll. The NtXxx API is the point where control jumps to kernel mode by executing INT 2E/SYSENTER.

**Kernel mode:** This involves writing a driver. Again, in kernel mode there are many places where you can install hook:

- SSDT hook: Install an SSDT hook for the required ZwXxx API (ZwQueryDirectoryFile in this case) by overwriting the corresponding SSDT index with the address of trampoline function in your driver.
- Kernel inline hook: Overwrite the first few instructions of NT kernel API exported by kernel (NtQueryDirectoryFile in this case) with a JMP to point to trampoline function in your driver.
- File system filter driver: This is a cleaner approach and no hooks are involved. Install a file system filter driver and intercept read/write/enumerate IOCTLs and filter out the results to hide/lock a specific file/folder.

Kernel mode hook tend to be cleaner as they generally installed at one "centralized place". However, you should be very careful as a small mistake/mishandling in driver code can end up with a BSOD.

PS: There are many hooking library/frameworks available to ease the job of writing code. Some popular ones are:
http://www.madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm 
http://easyhook.codeplex.com/

PPS: Hiding files/folders using such techniques without user's consent might be a questionable action and can become problematic (Remember Sony DRM protection software issue? ;) ). This is what rootkits do! There are many user mode and kernel mode rootkits that use the techniques mentioned above to hide files/folders. There are various anti-rootkit software available to detect and restore all sorts of hooking described above. Many anti-virus software raise a flag when they detect such rootkit like behavior (like API hooking, hidden files, SSDT hooks etc.)

Few resources:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/APIHooking.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/funapihook.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/api_spying_hack.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hide-driver.aspx 
http://www.uc-forum.com/forum/c-and-c/59147-writing-drivers-perform-kernel-level-ssdt-hooking.html
http://www.security.org.sg/code/apihookcheck.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that would be using [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to override the functions you need. It can also be used to inject the DLL, but you already have that covered. If there's a specific function used by the other process that is known to you, hook on that. If not, you'll need to hook on the building blocks of all functions used to list files or open them. Hooking just CreateFile/FindFirst/FindFirstFile/etc would be enough as they just call an internal function. For example, if you hook CreateFile which actually maps to CreateFileA, the process will still be able to access the file using CreateFileW. So you want to hook NtCreateFile and friends. But I guess you know which process you're messing with, so you know exactly which functions to mess with too.

Comment: I already hooked FindFirstFile and FindFirstFileEx, but they are not called when the program lists files. Is there any other function that it could be using? And when you say "I guess you know what process you're messing with, so you know..." actually that is the problem, since I can hook functions but I'm not sure which to hook.

Comment: Have you hooked both FindFirstFileA and FindFirstFileW? Have you tried API Monitor http://www.apimonitor.com/ ? If you don't know what it's using, and you don't want to disassemble to dig deeper, you can always catch them all with the lowest level function - NtQueryDirectoryFile and probably NtQueryDirectoryObject too.

Comment: No, I haven't hooked FindFirstFileA and W. And NtQueryDirectory* is a good idea, I didn't know about that, thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, best way is to open it up in OllyDbg/IDA and figure out what exactly it's calling. Would save you the trouble of writing something too generic and therefore complex.

Comment: I already have, and the code is complicated complicated and I can't figure out what it calls. It also has all the exports stripped from the program, so that makes it more difficult.